# My code keeps going out of bounds

Tags: java

I am trying to find all possible palindromes in a substring. I created a `palindrome` method which works but for some reason my code goes out of bounds instead of stopping after the last letter.

```
public static boolean palindrome(String input){

    int i = input.length(); 
    int k; 
    char[] palindrome_arr = new char[i];

    char[] palindrome_arr1 = new char[i];
    boolean result;

    palindrome_arr = input.toCharArray(); 
    for(k = 0; k<(i);k++)
    {
        //  System.out.println(palindrome_arr[k]);
        palindrome_arr1[k]=palindrome_arr[(palindrome_arr.length-1)-k]; 
        //System.out.println(palindrome_arr1[k]); 
        //   System.out.println(palindrome_arr[(palindrome_arr.length-1)-k]); 
    }
    result = Arrays.equals(palindrome_arr, palindrome_arr1);//checks if its a //palindrome
    if (result==true)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else 
        return false; 
}

for (String sub11 : sub1) {
    System.out.println(sub11);
    String sub2;
    sub2 = sub11;
    for (int q = 0; q < sub2.length()-1; q++)
    {                          
        sub = sub2.substring(q, sub2.length()-q);
        //  System.out.println(sub);
        If(sub.length() > 1){
            if(palindrome(sub) == true){
                System.out.println(sub);
                counter++;
                hm.put(counter, sub);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Formatting and readability matter.  Your code doesn't follow Java coding standards or pay any discernible attention to formatting.  No wonder you're having problems.  A debugger will tell you what you're doing wrong faster than a question here.

Comment: `sub2.substring(q, sub2.length()-q)` will fail once `q` is more than half the length. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @shmosel i've looked at the math several times, do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Did you use a debugger as @duffymo suggested?

Answer (score -1):

Your error is here.

```
sub = sub2.substring(q, sub2.length()-q);
```

For example, sub2.length is 5. And on the 4th iteration when q will be 3 and (sub2.length-q) is 2 and your values in the method will be sub2.substring(3, 2);

First value should not be greater than 2nd value, if it is greater then it will through the Out of bounds exception.

I gave you a basic idea, now change this code to make it fine.